# How to use TDD for a project that does a lot of network requests?

Tags: azure, testing, tdd, google-compute-engine, aws-sdk

I am working for a startup and am getting sick of the edit & pray development cycle (and the slow development time) and would like to bring in some TDD principles. I'm thinking about setting this up for our python project that pushes production code to various platforms like AWS GCE and Azure. I can't figure out how to write fast unit tests that cover all the cases of a production code push. I need to test things like deleting and creating images/instances which take a long time. Is there any way to test this in a quick manner or is TDD not the right approach for such a project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A test that does a production push is no longer a unit test, that's a system test or functional test, and hence will be heavy-weight to run.

In general, you should test the code that you wrote for your app in unit tests and run them frequently, and you should run functional/system tests regularly, but asynchronously, e.g., as part of continuous integration, but not as part of a TDD-style development where running such tests is in the critical path of your development.

You *could* attempt to mock/fake these systems, but it's most likely not worth it, because you won't be able to use the output of a fake image build, and hence the rest of the test doesn't really run.